# Double dual of the simple module in local algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a local Artin algebra that is not selfinjective with simple module $S$. 
Questions:

> 1. Can $S^{**}$ be indecomposable?
> 2. $S^{**}$ be somehow generally be described (for example as a nice direct sum of some ideals)?

Here $(-)^{*}$ denotes the functor $Hom_A(-,A)$.